# how to update a field value using triggers in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to use MongoDB triggers to call a function that will update a field in a specific collection

I did go through the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/trigger-snippets/#send-an-sms-on-new-document-inserts)  but all I did found was sending emails.

Comment: Did you solve the end Mohammed? Updating  field only with a trigger?

Comment: not yet, however allI can do is to write some kind of delegation to an update field method with id, this method is functional (interface) that you inject and use in your updating repo.
mongo need triggers